# Update Props before Rendering (Asynchronous call via Redux Action)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Looking for some direction here.  Here is my scenario:

- User is on a page that renders meta data from all recipes.
- User clicks on a recipe, gets sent to /recipes/:id which renders the Recipe component.  In the Recipe component in ComponentDidMount() contains a call to a Redux action which makes an asynchronous AXIOS call back to my server.  Data gets put onto the props and rendered onto the screen.
- User clicks back which brings them to the all recipes page.  They click on another recipe which takes them to the individual recipe page.  HERE IS THE ISSUE:  For a brief second the previous recipe.name (props) is displayed while the asynchronous call finishes from the AXIOS/redux request.

So the question is.  How do wait to get the new props from the asynchronous redux action before rendering data when a user goes to any of the /recipes/:id to ensure they are not seeing stale data on props.

Cheers!

Comment: Another way to approach the problem would be to wipe stale data out of the state when user navigates away from the recipe page.

Comment: If component props is linked to your Redux state, all you should have to do is call your redux thunk to fetch recipe. That's should use Axios and update state and have your component re-render automatically.

Comment: You have lots of options here. One option is to unmount the `Recipe` component on transition between recipe to index page, remounting it each time `recipes/:id` is received is received by the router. 

Another, and probably simpler option, is to just wait until the fetch has completed before rendering the component (making a synchronous call before rendering)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook, here you can call an action to clear the now redundant recipe data.

Comment: Hey Richard.  Thanks for the response.  So use componentwillUnmount to dispatch an action to clear the current state?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively you could clear the current recipe when returning to the all recipes route with `componentDidMount` on the all recipes component